# Why is my GestureDetector onTap event not firing?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I've created a custom form field and in it is a GestureDetector but the onTap is not firing. I want to use the GestureDetector to collect the click event when someone clicks on the form field in a disabled state so I can launch a dialog box. Code is below. I'm wondering what I must be doing wrong or misunderstanding.

```
Widget _customFormField(
    {required String title,
    required String initialValue,
    required int maxLines,
    required int maxLength,
    required bool enabled,
    required TextEditingController controller,
    bool autoFocus = false,
    required FocusNode currentFocusNode,
    required FocusNode futureFocusNode,
    Function? function,
    bool formEnd = false}) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(title,
          style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Ariel',
              color: Colors.pink)),

      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('onTap');  // <-------------------- This never gets hit
          function;
        },
        child: TextFormField(
          autofocus: autoFocus,
          enabled: enabled,
          textInputAction:
              formEnd ? TextInputAction.done : TextInputAction.next,
          onEditingComplete: () =>
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(futureFocusNode),
          focusNode: currentFocusNode,
          controller: controller,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              if (_formValid) {
                _formValid = false;
                currentFocusNode.requestFocus();
              }
              //title.toLowerCase()
              return 'Please enter the ${title.toLowerCase()}';
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

I've tried changing it to an InkWell but it behaves the same.

I've removed some styling code from the example but nothing that could have an affect on the problem.

Comment: are sure you're not pointing on why `function` is not executing ?

Answer (score 0):

well the `function` property that you got from the properties are the definition of the method, when you do :

```
  onTap: () {
          print('onTap');
          function;
        },
```

you not calling the method, you putting it there, you need to call it so it runs, by adding `()` or by calling `call()` on it.

```
  onTap: () {
          print('onTap');
          function(); // like this
          // function.call();  or like this
        },
```

Comment: Thank you, tried your changes to the function however as I suspected they did not solve the problem. The print statement isn't hit so neither is the function call.

Comment: Upon further investigation I found that the onTap event is somehow being eaten by the child FormField. if I disable the field (set its enabled property to false) then the onTap event fires.

Further more I was finally able to get the results I wanted by changing the GestureDetector to a Listener and using the onPointerDown event. Not quite the same as onTap but for my purposes it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
onTap: () {
          print('onTap');  // <-------------------- This never gets hit
          if (function != null) function.call();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, tried your changes to the function however as I suspected they did not solve the problem. The print statement isn't hit so neither is the function call.

Comment: Upon further investigation I found that the onTap event is somehow being eaten by the child FormField. if I disable the field (set its enabled property to false) then the onTap event fires.

Further more I was finally able to get the results I wanted by changing the GestureDetector to a Listener and using the onPointerDown event. Not quite the same as onTap but for my purposes it worked.